# switching angular versions for build

Tags: angular

Is it feasible to configure my project to build with different angular versions ,say 4 & 5. we want to switch between angular versions depending upon requirements, is there a way to configure this.

Comment: is it in local or a continuous integration in environment?

Comment: Of course. Why wouldn't it be? But why do that in the first place? Why not just use the latest version? It can do whetever the previous version allowed to do, doesn't it?